# Using the Excel's Rank() function to calculate allocations based on ranking and constraints

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table set up

```
Limit  Allocation  Yield    Ranking
$600    [to calc]   0.07%    7
$600                0.09%    6
$600                0.20%    1
$400                0.20%    1
$400                0.13%    4
$200                0.19%    3
$200                0.12%    5
```

Additionally, I have a constraint which I could only allocate a total of **$2000** across the 7 rows here, by the rankings of their yield (so a higher yield would get everything allocated up to the `limit` column if there is any left overs from the $2000 total).

I was wondering how I could set up the equations so that it could perform the allocation automatically.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume this table starts in A1...

In E1, put the amount you have to allocate

In B2 (and then copied to B3...B8) use the following formula

```
=MIN(A2,$E$1-SUMIF($D$2:$D$8,">"&D2,$B$2:$B$8))
```

This will work out how much has been taken by higher ranked, and take the rest, upto whatever is the lesser amount of their limit, and what is left in the pot.
There is one fault with this equation that you will need to figure out how to handle:
If there are equal ranks at the end of the distribution, then both will get the final amount. (e.g. try this with $2,001, and you will see that the 2 rows that have then rank **1** will both claim the final dollar)

Answer (score -2):

Answer to solve the ties for rank causing problem.  In the rank column D, add to the rank =rank(c2,$c$2:$c$8,0) + (.0000001 * row(a2)), or whatever row you are in.  Then format the rank column to only show integers.  Doing this makes the very small decimal addition to the rank the tie breaker so the first row with the rank's matching integer will take the allocation.  Since you are adding it to the rank, it doesn't effect any totals.  By changing the column format display to integer, the viewer will not be aware of the tiebreaker.