# Using Excel to allocate values based off their rank while remaining within constraints

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a resource calculator that can tell me how many people i need to put on each section depending on the current work waiting and work coming in. Prioritizing sections which have the most work waiting first.

```
Upper Limit     Allocation  Prod    Ranking
12               [to calc]   28%      1
15                           18%      2 
5                            17%      3
4                             8%      4
2                             6%      5
3                            .2%      6
4                            .2%      6
```

Similar to the other question I have a constraint that i only have so much to allocate. For this example we will use 38 as the amount that is to be allocated.

I have used the formula from the other answer:

```
 =MIN(A2,$E$1-SUMIF($D$2:$D$8,"<"&D2,$B$2:$B$8))
```

Where E1 contains the total to be allocated.

I have two issues with this formula:
1)The issue that I am having is that I require a minimum value of atleast 1 person in each of these sections.

I have tried using a max function to simply set this value, however this leads to the resources allocated going over the total amount.
What equation would I need to use to make it account for both the total available to allocate, the minimum requirement for each fund and the maximum limit for each fund.

2) It only returns solid integers, would there be a way to retreive more precise results, maybe by changing it to a % distribution?

```
UL  Alloc   Rank    Capacity    Lower Limit
2   1        15      93          1
3   1        15     
4   1        15     
6   6        8      
1   1        15     
2   1        15     
4   4        9      
2   2        7      
4   4        4      
15  15       2      
12  12      10      
12  12      1       
1   1       11      
13  13      5       
6   6       6       
5   1       15      
5   5       3       
1   1       14      
2   2       13      
3   3       12      
3   1       15
```

Reference: [Using the Excel's Rank() function to calculate allocations based on ranking and constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681381/using-the-excels-rank-function-to-calculate-allocations-based-on-ranking-and?newreg=42eed1d6b6fd487cbbf70d396d46c172)

Comment: Data Set changed from original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Simply subtract the 100 on all sides and add them separately:

   `=MIN(A2-100,($E$1-100*COUNTA($A$2:$A$8))-(SUMIF($D$2:$D$8,"<"&D2,$B$2:$B$8)-COUNTIF($D$2:$D$8,"<"&D2)*100))+100`
2. What is returned depends on your entries in Column A and in E1. You can change Column A based on a percentage distribution and the formula will return the corresponding values.

*Edit*:

If you set your lower threshold into F2, your Constraint into E2, using this formula

```
=MIN(A2-$F$2,($E$2-$F$2*COUNTA($A$2:$A$8))-(SUMIF($D$2:$D$8,"<"&D2,$B$2:$B$8)-COUNTIF($D$2:$D$8,"<"&D2)*$F$2))+$F$2
```

the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this formula doesn't give me the correct answer if my lower requirement where to change to a more difficult number to use such as 1. I have adjusted the data set to make it more similar to my own to see if that helps me convey the problem better.

Comment: For your reference, when substituting the 100 for 1's this led to multiple negative numbers

Comment: Did you replace all 100's? Try this formula and type in the Lower Requirement into F1: `=MIN(A2-$F$1,($E$1-$F$1*COUNTA($A$2:$A$8))-(SUMIF($D$2:$D$8,"<"&D2,$B$2:$B$8)-COUNTIF($D$2:$D$8,"<"&D2)*$F$1))+$F$1`

Comment: Hello @LukasV, Thanks this worked great. The only issue I have now is that when I approach maximum capacity the formula becomes incorrect because of the fact that their multiple qual ranks

I have added an additional data set to the initial question to illustrate this.
At a capacity of 93 the formula is correct however anywhere between 94-106 (my absolute maximum capacity) the formula is incorrect. 
Is there a way to take this into account?

Comment: That's a tricky one. The only thing I can think of is that you adjust your ranking, avoiding double entries. You can use this forumula `=RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$22,1)+COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)-1`, however be aware that with this formula it is always the first number that will get advantaged.